# Conditional Tags and Echo HTML / divs or CSS and Display: none?

Tags: conditional-tags

If I wanted to show a slider on the home page only, is it better or does it make a difference if I:

- use a PHP if/then statement and echo a division and markup, or
- use CSS along with a body class and display none the division? or
- a combination of both

What's the best practice?

Comment: Conditional Tags is Good Option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target homepage only with if statement.

```
if ( is_front_page() or is_home() )

}
```

if your home page has page/2 page/3 then use the following to display the slider on only page 1 of the homepage.

```
if ( is_front_page() or is_home() && ! is_paged() ) {

}
```

Comment: Important to note, that I used `or` for a reason. It's more lightweight than `||` and `&&` so the first one will be checked first and than compared to the result or `! is_paged()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_front_page() or is_home() )
{
    // Your Slider Code
}
```